# why setXXX() method is not overrinding?

Tags: java

I have super class called `pojo`. I have a subclass called `ExtendPojo`.

### pojo.java

```
package com.java.pojo;

public class pojo {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "pojo [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", number=" + number + "]";
    }

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private long number;
}
```

---

### ExtendPojo.java

```
package com.java.pojo;

public class ExtendPojo extends pojo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        pojo obj = new pojo();
        obj.setName("santhosh");

        ExtendPojo exObj = new ExtendPojo();
        exObj.setName("mahesh");//It is not overriding

        System.out.println(obj.getName());//it prints santhosh.


    }

    public void setName(String name){
        super.setName(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are Overriding to me. You have `super.setName(name);` in your overridden method in `ExtendPojo`. This calls the parent's method. As is, your overridden method is useless. On a side-note, you should really put the `@Override` annotation above methods you are overriding.

Comment: Your test is not able to differentiate whether or not the method is overridden.

Comment: Just remove `super.setName(name);` from your `ExtendedPojo.setName` and add what you want to do

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: I think you have some misconceptions about what overriding means, and possibly about differences between classes and instances. The program works as it should work.

Comment: You seem confused about inheritance and overriding. Overriding a method won't make one instance see another's data. Also your override is pointless since it just delegates to the superclass. You might want to do some more reading.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I have written ExtendPojo exObj = new ExtendPojo(); instead of Pojo exObj = new ExtendPojo();. It is overriding now. Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two *independent* objects.

First you create an object and name it `santhosh`. This object is referenced by the `obj` variable.

> ```
> pojo obj = new pojo();
> obj.setName("santhosh");
> ```

Then you create a *second* object, which is referenced by the `exObj` variable.

> ```
> ExtendPojo exObj = new ExtendPojo();
> ```

It doesn't have a name yet, since it's a new object and you haven't assigned the name. You then give it a name.

> ```
> exObj.setName("mahesh");//It is not overriding
> ```

Now you print the name of the *first* object, which hasn't changed.

> ```
> System.out.println(obj.getName());//it prints santhosh.
> ```

*The code is doing exactly what you asked it to do.*

If you intended the two variables to reference the *same* object, you'd do this:

```
ExtendPojo exObj = new ExtendPojo();

pojo obj = exObj ;//Same object, new variable, different type
obj.setName("santhosh");

exObj.setName("mahesh");//It is working now

System.out.println(obj.getName());//it prints mahesh.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the Inheritance and method overriding concepts and clarified my doubts :)

```
public class ExtendPojo extends Pojo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pojo obj = new Pojo();
        obj.setName("santhosh");

        Pojo obj1 = new ExtendPojo();
        obj1.setName("mahesh");//It is overriding now

        System.out.println(obj1.getName());//it prints mahesh.

    }
}
```